# JerseyでPOSTの際に配列を受け取るにはどうすれば良いんでしょうか…

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

@FormParam(パラメータ名) String[] 配列名
では上手くいかなかったのですが、調べてもわからなかったので質問させて頂きました。
もし分かる方がいらっしゃれば、教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1):

`@FormParam(パラメーター名) List<String> リスト名` といった形でいかがでしょうか。

完全に同趣旨かはわかりませんが、本家のStack Overflowの方で近しい質問がされていて、それに対する回答がついていました。

[post - JAX RS Jersey Rest Webservice posting a array generated by input from user - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183274/jax-rs-jersey-rest-webservice-posting-a-array-generated-by-input-from-user)

Comment: tkhmさん
回答ありがとうございます。
Listはokなんですね。勉強になりましたm(_ _)m